# Bokeh DateRangeSlider

Tags: python, slider, bokeh

I have recently started working in Bokeh, finished some quick course on datacamp and I got stuck on creating a DateRangeSlider. Slider itself looks ok to me, changing the values on the slider works, but I can't make it to change the plot.

Not sure what am I missing as I can't find proper tutorials / info on using this particular tool, so any help on that would be highly appreciated.

Here's the code:

```
data['periodFrom'] = pd.to_datetime(data['periodFrom']).dt.date
data = data.rename(columns={'MWh/h' : 'MWH'})
source = ColumnDataSource(data={
    'x'       : data.periodFrom,
    'y'       : data.MWH,
    'point'      : data.pointLabel,
    'direction'      : data.directionKey
})
xmin, xmax = min(data.periodFrom), max(data.periodFrom)
ymin, ymax = min(data['MWH']), max(data['MWH'])

plot = figure(title='Gas renomination', plot_height=400, plot_width=700,
              x_range=(xmin, xmax), y_range=(ymin, ymax))

plot.line(x='x', y='y', source=source)

plot.xaxis.axis_label ='Date'
plot.yaxis.axis_label = 'MWh/h'

def update_plot(attr, old, new):
    yr = slider.value
    new_data = {
    'x'       : data.loc[yr[0]:yr[1]].periodFrom,
    'y'       : data.loc[yr[0]:yr[1]].MWH,
    'point'      : data.loc[yr[0]:yr[1]].pointLabel,
    'direction'      : data.loc[yr[0]:yr[1]].directionKey
    }
    source.data = new_data

slider = DateRangeSlider(start=date(2016,1,1), end=date.today(), step=1, 
         value=(date(2016,1,1),date(2016,2,1)), title='Date', width=1000)

slider.on_change('value', update_plot)

curdoc().add_root(plot)
curdoc().add_root(slider)
show(plot)
```

And here's the error message I get in the commmand prompt every time I change slider's value:

```
2018-07-19 11:56:55,387 error handling message Message 'PATCH-DOC' (revision 1): KeyError(1451606400000,)
```

Best,
Piotrek

**EDIT:**

I did some work on the slider, now not raising any errors, but the plot vanishes when I move the slider in any direction. Individually filtering works well (i.e. when I put 'data[data.index > yr[0]].periodFrom' in the console), but it seems like there's something wrong with updating the plot with new values.

```
data['periodFrom'] = pd.to_datetime(data['periodFrom'])
data.index = data['periodFrom'].astype(np.int64) // 10 ** 9
data.index = data.index.astype(np.float)

data = data.rename(columns={'MWh/h' : 'MWH'})
source = ColumnDataSource(data={
    'x'       : data.periodFrom,
    'y'       : data.MWH,
    'point'      : data.pointLabel,
    'direction'      : data.directionKey
})

xmin, xmax = min(data.periodFrom), max(data.periodFrom)
ymin, ymax = min(data['MWH']), max(data['MWH'])

# Create the figure: plot
plot = figure(title='Gas renomination', plot_height=400, plot_width=700,
              x_range=(xmin, xmax), y_range=(ymin, ymax))

plot.line(x='x', y='y', source=source)

plot.xaxis.axis_label ='Date'
plot.yaxis.axis_label = 'MWh/h'

#slider
def update_plot(attr, old, new):
    yr = slider.value
    yr=list(yr)
    [float(i) for i in yr]
    new_data = {
        'x' : data[(data.index > yr[0]) & (data.index < yr[1])].periodFrom,
        'y' : data[(data.index > yr[0]) & (data.index < yr[1])].MWH,
        'point' : data[(data.index > yr[0]) & (data.index < yr[1])].pointLabel,
        'direction' : data[(data.index > yr[0]) & (data.index < yr[1])].directionKey}

print(new_data)
source.data = new_data

slider = DateRangeSlider(start=datetime(2016,1,2).timestamp(), 
end=datetime.today().timestamp(), step=1, value= 
(datetime(2016,2,2).timestamp(),datetime(2016,3,3).timestamp()), title='Date', 
width=1000)
slider.on_change('value', update_plot)

#dropdown

def update_dropdown(attr, old, new):
    point_select = select.value
    data_selected ={
        'x' : data[data['pointLabel'] == point_select].periodFrom,
        'y' : data[data['pointLabel'] == point_select].MWH,
        'point' : data[data['pointLabel'] == point_select].pointLabel,
        'direction' : data[data['pointLabel'] == point_select].directionKey}

    source.data=data_selected

select = Select(title="Point", options=pointlabels, value='Kondratki')
select.on_change('value', update_dropdown)

curdoc().add_root(select)
curdoc().add_root(plot)
curdoc().add_root(slider)
```

My original dataframe is 40639 x 6, after printing new_data i get a dict:

[image: dict image]

I also added a Select widget in the second part of the code, data_selected is the same format as in DateRangeSlider (see: image). What's strange for me is that Select works perfectly, while DataRangeSlider makes the plot vanish every time I click it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although sliders can be initialized with datetime objects for convenience, the slider value is actually represented as a floating point timestamp, specificically, the number of milliseconds since epoch. That means your attempts to index your dataframe directly with the value are roughly equivalent to:

```
data.loc[1451606400000].periodFrom
```

Which does not work for obvious reasons.

Based on the name `yr`, it looks like you want to index your dataframe with values that are years? Then you need to convert the timestamp value to a real datetime and extra the year:

```
In [6]: from datetime import datetime

In [7]: datetime.fromtimestamp(1451606400000/1000).year
Out[7]: 2015
```

As an aside, there is never a reason to use or call `show` in a Bokeh server application.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot! I'm actually indexing with a full date, but I guess I can handle this myself from now on. Cheers!

Comment: could you please have a look at the updated post? your solution has helped a lot, but I'm still struggling with connecting slider values with plot.

Comment: I can't really say anything else without a complete example to run. But what I would do is add some print statements to the callback to examine the variable values to see that they are what I expect (or if they aren't) and you can do that as well.

Comment: sure, I added some code and a screenshot, if you want i can post the data somewhere so you can run the example. print statement in the mid of update_plot returns 4 times pandas series and 'Name: periodFrom, Length: 934, dtype: datetime64[ns]' after each series.

Answer (score 0):

the DateRangeSlider has the attribute value_as_date which makes the tuple's elements on date format, you just have to make it:

```
yr = slider.value_as_date
```